Tooltip triggers after clicking outside dropdown menu
Hello I have a tooltip and a dropdown menu.
If I trigger the dropdown, and click outside the dropdown or inside the dropdown, the tooltip content is triggered again.
so, if I hover over the button, it triggers the tooltip correctly. if I click on the button itself then the dropdown is triggered correctly, but then if I clickoutside the dropdown to close it or click inside the dropdown contents, dropdown closes correctly but it triggers the tooltip again, incorrectly.
<DropdownMenu>
  <Tooltip>
    <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
      <TooltipTrigger asChild>
        <Button variant="ghost">
          Type
          <BiFilter className="ml-2 h-5 w-5" />
        </Button>
      </TooltipTrigger>
    </DropdownMenuTrigger>
    <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
      <DropdownMenuRadioGroup
        value={filter}
        onValueChange={handleFilterChange}
      >
        {ValuesToMap.map((value) => (
          <DropdownMenuRadioItem key={value} value={value}>
            value
          </DropdownMenuRadioItem>
        ))}
      </DropdownMenuRadioGroup>
    </DropdownMenuContent>
    <TooltipContent>
      Filter By Type
    </TooltipContent>
  </Tooltip>
</DropdownMenu>


Update your DropdownMenuContent as below:
<DropdownMenuContent align="end" onCloseAutoFocus={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
  <DropdownMenuRadioGroup value={filter} onValueChange={handleFilterChange}>
    {ValuesToMap.map((value) => (
      <DropdownMenuRadioItem key={value} value={value}>
        value
      </DropdownMenuRadioItem>
    ))}
  </DropdownMenuRadioGroup>
</DropdownMenuContent>

Changes:

We have to prevent shifting the focus back to trigger button while we are closing DropdownMenu with outer click

Here you can learn more

This works for DropDown and solves the original question. However, the same behavior occurs when opening a FileUploader (from "react-aria-components"), so I wish the solution was in the Tooltip itself and not in the other components.
